# Flutter widget not running initState and passing it into a Widget correctly

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the below code, and the idea is that when the user logs in, they are pushed to this page ('dashboard'). I am trying to use `initState` to make the app run the function `takenSurvey2()`, which then creates a value for the bool `takenSurvey`. This comes from querying Cloud Firestore.

The value for the bool `takenSurvey` would then be used in the Stack's Positioned widget to determine which icon to show the user (if the user hasn't taken the survey (i.e. `takenSurvey`  = false) they would be shown a 'new' icon.

However what happens at the moment is that when the user logs in and the page loads, and the error icon shows, so the widget thinks that `takenSurvey` does not have a value of true or false. However, when I create an arbitrary button and use `OnPressed` to print the value of `takenSurvey`, it shows up as 'false' in the console. When I hot reload the dashboard page the error icon turns to the 'new' icon, as I expected - why doesn't it do this straight away?

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and why the widget can't see the value of `takenSurvey`, even though `takenSurvey2()` has been run in `initState`, and I've wrapped it in a `Builder` widget?

```
      class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
      static const String id = 'dashboard';
      @override
      _DashboardState createState() => _DashboardState();
    }

    class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
      final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
      var userid;
      String surveyName;
      bool takenSurvey;
      String title;

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getCurrentUser();
    getUserID();
    currentSurveyName();
    takenSurvey2();
  }

void takenSurvey2() async {
    final snapShot = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('$surveyName' + '_entrants')
        .document(userid)
        .get();
    if (snapShot.exists) {
      takenSurvey = true;
    } else {
      takenSurvey = false;
    }
  }

 @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
               Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                      child: SquareButton(
                          buttonTitle: "",
                          fontSize: 36,
                          onPressed: () async {
                            final snapShot = await Firestore.instance
                                .collection('$surveyName' + '_entrants')
                                .document(userid)
                                .get();
                            if (snapShot.exists) {
                              _alreadyCompletedSurveyError();
                            } else if (surveyName.isEmpty)
                              _otherError();
                            else {
                              return Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  new MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                          new TestSurvey(surveyName)));
                            }
                          }),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      right: 30,
                      top: 20,
                      child: Builder(builder: (context) {
                        if (takenSurvey == false) {
                          return Icon(
                            Foundation.burst_new,
                            size: 48,
                            color: Color(0xff303841),
                          );
                        } else if (takenSurvey == true) {
                          return Icon(
                            Foundation.check,
                            size: 48,
                            color: Color(0xff303841),
                          );
                        } else
                          return Icon(
                            MaterialIcons.error,
                            size: 48,
                            color: Color(0xff303841),
                          );
                      }),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text('Latest Survey',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 36,
                              fontFamily: "Roboto")),
```

Comment: `takenSurvey2` is an `async` function and the return type should be changed to `Future<void>`. You can not `await` for async code in `initState`, it must be synchronous. Use a `FutureBuilder` to correctly show the data in the `build` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice that widgets build() method is synchronous, so it runs immediately on Flutter need and could be called as many times as framework need it, not called once

Secondly notice your takenSurvey has no default value and it initialized with null

So what happens next:

1. when the your widget gets into the tree initState is called
2. your async routines starts
3. build() method is called by framework and first frame is rendered
4. takenSurvey == null that's why error Icon is shown
5. sometime later your async routines completes (never before first frame) and takenSurvey value setted true/false
6. missed step - notify Flutter that routine is completed and we got some data to show

What about button pressed or hot reload - you doing this after your routine is completed, if you hit them before - you'll see null

Hot reload does rebuild tree and finally you can see data on screen

First simpliest fix to your code is to call setState() at the end of void takenSurvey2() routine - this will rebuild you widget(flutter reruns build())

```
void takenSurvey2() async {
   final snapShot = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('$surveyName' + '_entrants')
      .document(userid)
      .get();
   if (snapShot.exists) {
     takenSurvey = true;
   } else {
     takenSurvey = false;
   }
   setState((){});
}
```

Surely you need to deal with takenSurvey == null - you need to show to user Loading indicator because you perform some async action but user does not knows what it's going on

Second and more convinient way is to use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) (it's up to you to finish next code snippet to make it work, fill free to ask in comments)

```
    FutureBuilder(
        future: Firestore.instance
          .collection('$surveyName' + '_entrants')
          .document(userid)
          .get(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data.exists) {
              _alreadyCompletedSurveyError();
            } else if (surveyName.isEmpty)
              _otherError();
              ... more code
          } else {
            // show loading
          }
        },
      )
```

And the last advice - you need to learn State Managment and how to separate logic from widgets.

You will need it on your developer way.

Start here
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt

Comment: This is great, thank you - but would the future builder work for my Positioned widget, where I want to change the icon based on what is returned?

Comment: To make future result visible to your Positioned move FutureBuilder upper in tree

`FutureBuilder(builder: (ctx) => Stack(children: [ your widgets here  ]))`

Answer (score -2):

can you try adding a async func in initstate?

```dart
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    test();
  }

void test() async {
    await getCurrentUser();
    await getUserID();
    await currentSurveyName();
    await takenSurvey2();
}
```

Comment: This code is no different than what the OP already has other than wrapping it in a function, which has no effect.